# Workflow Email Notification

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow

How would I make a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 (for SharePoint 2013 on-premise) that sends out a notification to a person one week after the date `datecolumn one` passes and then continues to send out a notification every day until the date reaches the `due date column` which is another week out?

Thusfare, I have edited the column formula '[due date column]-7' to represent the date that the notifications will start... Next I have I made the work flow.... but am not sure how to approach it... I have to send the email to the people that are relative to the project and I am not sure as how to reference them from there login... please help. I currently refer to them as approveres and there are 4 stages to the approval process.

Could someone tell me what is a good way to start this... how do ...

Comment: SharePoint version would be helpful. 2007, 2010, 2013, online?